# Simple Jquery Dialog but now on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dialog, onclick

I tried making a dialog using jquery it works but I have no succes at doing it onclick bacuse it should not just popup but only when you click on it.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$.ui.dialog.defaults.bgiframe = true;
$(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog();
});
</script>
```

and

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <p>hi how are you</p>
</div>
```

and for the nice looking button

```
<button id="create-user" class="ui-button ui-state-default ui-corner-all">Profiel Matthijs</button>
```

tried using these examples

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/
http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form

anyone know how to get this working with an click on the #create-user button
i am not so good at javascript.

Thanks
Matthy

Comment: "I have no succes at doing it onclick bacuse it should not just popup but only when you click on it." aren't both the same thing? When do you want your dialog box appear can you rephrase?

Comment: ok understand what you mean, because you fire it at document ready function it popups when page loads... the answers are fair enough below i think then...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set the `autoOpen` option to false so that the dialog will not open when its created.

To open it when your button is clicked, you would call the open method.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $.ui.dialog.defaults.bgiframe = true;
    $(function() {
        $('#dialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: false
        });
        $('#create-user').click(function() {
            $('#dialog').dialog('open');
        });
    });
</script>
```